# What does the stack of this function look like?

Tags: jvm

I have to following question.

Given is the function:

```
show(int a, int b) 
{
    int v1;
    int v2;
}
```

a and b are parameters. v1 en v2 are local variables. Draw a stack in which its is clear where a, b, v1 , v2, the old frame pointer en the return adress are. Also show where the high and low stack addresses are.

I hope i have been clear enough.

Edit:

What i have now is:

```
v2      <-- SP
v1
prevLV  <-- LV
Ra
a
b
```

Comment: What i have now from bottom to top. b - a - rA - prevLV - v1 - v2. With LV --> prevLV and SP--> v2

Comment: What architecture is this?  x86?  MIPS?  SPARC?

Answer (score 0):

Drawing a definitive picture is hard as it depends on the implementation of the JVM, but what you have now is VERY unlikely to be correct.

Because Java doesn't distinguish args from temps (see the iload, etc.. bytecodes), they're going to need to appear side by side in memory, or someone's going to have to copy them from the caller pending stack to the callee at frame construction time (which tends to be expensive).